# Unknow character when convert .xlsx to .csv and import to mongodb?

Tags: excel, mongodb, csv

I got a weird error when import .csv file to mongodb. Here's step by step I did:

**Step 1:** I got a .xlsx and convert to .csv with UTF-8 encoding

My test.xlsx:

```
index   count
1   12
2   14
3   12
4   43



  Step 1.1: save as .xlsx file with "Unicode Text (*.txt)"  
  Step 1.2: open .txt with nodepad and replace tab with ","
  Step 1.3: save as .txt and change the file extension from "*.txt" to "*.csv", and choose encoding: to UTF-8
```

**Step 2:** I import to mongodb with mongoimport in linux shell. Here's the output:

```
 mongoimport -d mydb -c test --type csv --file test.csv --headerline
mongoimport: /usr/lib64/libcrypto.so.10: no version information available (required by mongoimport)
mongoimport: /usr/lib64/libssl.so.10: no version information available (required by mongoimport)
2015-12-24T10:21:22.909+0700    connected to: localhost
2015-12-24T10:21:22.910+0700    imported 4 documents
```

**Step 3:** When I try find with index, I got nothing.

```
db.test.find({"index":"1"})
```

Then I use Robomongo to show my test collection and here I got:

[image]

You can see a weird character in index field?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would say its BOM (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Byte_order_mark).

Do you have an option to save as "Unicode without BOM"?

Alternatively you can clear the character when you read the input.

Comment: Thank for your help but How to exactly clear the character?